# rotate() in Eigen::Transform is not transforming my rotation matrix

Tags: matrix, rotation, transform, eigen

I have defined a rotation matrix and wanted the Eigen::Transform to perform rotation. For some reason, it is still set at identity although I am rotating it.

```
//Definig my rotation matrix
Eigen::Matrix3f roll_rotation_matrix( 3, 3 );
roll_rotation_matrix << 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0;

//Print
display("PRINT ROLL ROTATION: ")
display(roll_rotation_matrix)

// Perform rotation along X 
display("BEFORE: ")
display(roll_input_stamped_transform.transform.rotation())

//Rotate the rotation matrix
roll_input_stamped_transform.transform.rotate( roll_rotation_matrix );
roll_input_stamped_transform.transform.rotation = roll_rotation_matrix;

//Print
display(" AFTER: ")
display(roll_input_stamped_transform.transform.rotation());
```

And my output here is as below:
      PRINT ROLL ROTATION:
     1  0  0
     0  0  1
     0 -1  0

```
 BEFORE: 
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1

 AFTER: 
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

As I am printing my roll_rotation_matrix, I can see that my matrix is not identity. But, even after applying rotate(), the rotation matrix still seems to be at identity.
Do you guys have any clue as to what might me going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.
I had to set the `roll_input_stamped_transform.transform.setIdentity()` in order for it to apply my rotation matrix.